# extract specific keys from json and adding to objects within another array - couchdb view?

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I have some largish JSON data that looks a bit like

```
[
    {
        "_id": "d87f32bc-e2d7-4630-8007-2120f53bd41d",
        "_rev": "e9ce906d-0cb3-4a47-9f9c-963c78cced63",
        "topic": "ipsum magna nisi",
        "type": "inquiry",
        "person": {
            "name": "Marcia Smitham",
        },
        "investigation": [
            {
                "timestampResult": "2022-12-21 23:33:24"
            }
        ],
        "communication": [
            {
                "endTime": "2022-11-22 12:27:05"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "337f1d1f-419d-4c4e-adbe-0a06c7322c5e",
        "_rev": "abc60cae-a2ff-438b-bb2d-dc88f27674a0",
        "topic": "excepteur",
        "type": "other",
        "person": {
            "name": "Nora Kunde"
        },
        "investigation": [
            {
                "timestampResult": "2022-02-15 00:28:01"
            },
            {
                "timestampResult": "2022-12-05 01:17:58"
            },
            {
                "timestampResult": "2022-12-19 05:50:49"
            }
        ],
        "communication": [
            {
                "endTime": "2022-04-06 12:26:16"
            },
            {
                "endTime": "2022-07-27 05:06:00"
            },
            {
                "endTime": "2022-09-06 09:00:30",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to pick out the topics and types and create something like:

```
[
    { "label": "ipsum magna nisi", "type": "inquiry"},
    { "label": "excepteur", "type": "other"}
]
```

how would I go about it in the most efficient way? Ideally as a couchdb view, otherwise as normal javascript? The JSON docs are actually quite large so I don't want to do nested for loops if I can avoid it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop through the items and form the object as you like:

```js
let data = [{"_id":"d87f32bc-e2d7-4630-8007-2120f53bd41d","_rev":"e9ce906d-0cb3-4a47-9f9c-963c78cced63","topic":"ipsum magna nisi","type":"inquiry","person":{"name":"Marcia Smitham"},"investigation":[{"timestampResult":"2022-12-21 23:33:24"}],"communication":[{"endTime":"2022-11-22 12:27:05"}]},{"_id":"337f1d1f-419d-4c4e-adbe-0a06c7322c5e","_rev":"abc60cae-a2ff-438b-bb2d-dc88f27674a0","topic":"excepteur","type":"other","person":{"name":"Nora Kunde"},"investigation":[{"timestampResult":"2022-02-15 00:28:01"},{"timestampResult":"2022-12-05 01:17:58"},{"timestampResult":"2022-12-19 05:50:49"}],"communication":[{"endTime":"2022-04-06 12:26:16"},{"endTime":"2022-07-27 05:06:00"},{"endTime":"2022-09-06 09:00:30"}]}];

let res = data.map(d => ({label: d.topic, type:d.type}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: of course it would be so easy :)

Answer (score 0):

The couchdb version...

Inside a view:

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.topic && doc.type ){
    emit([doc._id, 1], {
        "label": doc.topic,
        "type": doc.type
    });
  }
}
```